# Что обозначает строка из исходников lighttpd? c++

Tags: c++, lighttpd

```
#define BINPATH SBIN_DIR"/lighttpd"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){//argv это char**
   *(const char **)&argv[0] = BINPATH;   
}
```

Comment: Присвоение `argv[0]` указателя на строковый литерал. С таким вывертом - из-за константности. Как мне представляется, UB.

Comment: Кстати, гуру в стандартах - чем это лучше, чем присваивание `argv[0] = (char*)"test";`?

Comment: @Harry, спасибо. Но непонятно для чего амерсанд и звездочка в начале, const char** это же и есть указатель на строковый литерал

Comment: @Harry мне кажется гуру в стандартах сюда не зайдут. Но если да то буду очень рад. А за что минус я как-то и не понял

Comment: `const char**` - указатель на указатель. Вы не можете использовать просто `(const char*)argv[0]` - это не будет lvalue. Вот для получения lvalue и делают такие чудеса...

Comment: Спасибо всем. Теперь я тоже задался вопрос почему бы не написать argv[0] = (char *) "string"; и тогда, как я понимаю, отличий по функциналу от исходной строки не будет.

Comment: @Александр, *`"почему бы не написать argv[0] = (char *) "string";"`* -- видимо чтобы "по взрослому" выглядело. Короче, не берите в голову, странных людей всююду хватает. Главное, чтобы компилировалось и правильно работало (в очерченных вами условиях прменения)

Comment: @avp понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контекст, я так понимаю, примерно такой:

```
#define BINPATH SBIN_DIR"/lighttpd" // Соединяем строку макроса SBIN_DIR с "/lighttpd", записываем в SBIN_DIR

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){//argv это char**
   *(const char **)&argv[0] = BINPATH;   
}
```

Расшифровка:

1. `argv[0]` - 0-ая строка, переданная в параметр
2. `&argv[0]` - её адрес (указатель на неё). Т.е. строка - указатель/массив символов, а мы берём адрес строки => мы берём указатель на указатель/массив символов
3. `(const char **)&argv[0]` - снимаем константность строки (можно было бы попробовать использовать const_cast<const char**>(&argv[0]) вместо этого)
4. `*(const char **)&argv[0]` - разыменовываем указатель на строку (указатель на массив символов/указатель), получаем - строку (просто массив символов/указатель)
5. `*(const char **)&argv[0] = BINPATH;` - присваиваем строке-аргументу командной строки при вызове программы, другую строку (с учётом константности - из-за которой была вся пляска с приведением типов), де факто - приравниваем один указатель на последовательность символов с другим (просто присваиваем адрес).

Nota bene: хотя такое (я про 5й шаг) в большинстве случаев и прокатывает, т.к. как правило, никто не трогает аргументы запуска программы, но вот если кто-то после 5го шага сделает, например так: `argv[0][0] = 'H'`, то можно ожидать undefined behavior: не константный argv позволяет изменять любой символ в строке, но т.к. мы ему присвоили адрес константной строки, то попытка модифицировать эту строку может иметь непредсказуемые последствия.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что было нужно. Если имя это и есть указатель на начало, то &argv[0] и argv должны быть эквивалентны, разве нет? В чем заключается разница?

Comment: Для понятности, что это нулевой элемент массива. Вы-же не будете заменять `&argv[N]` так `argv + N`.

Comment: Для понятности, но не только. Ещё типизация. Хотя и &argv[0], и argv - суть - один и тот же адрес, но вот так (const char\*)(*argv) = BINPATH; - сделать нельзя, т.к. в такой записи левый операнд не левостороннее значение: 
*(const char **)&argv[0] = BINPATH; - слева - сначала указатель, потом мы его разыменовали и дальше слева - переменная (тоже указатель), в которую кладём строку.
(const char\*)(*argv) = BINPATH; - а тут - слева - просто указатель (временный), в который строку нельзя положить. Разница как между:
*int_ptr = 4; и int() = 4;